# What is means of this?

Tags: c++, function

If the function is define like this in C++:

```
char *Func() {

 return "Text";
}
```

then;

```
Func()[] = 'a';
```

Means what?

Comment: _'Means what?'_ That you are prone to fail miserably, in whatever you're trying to do with this!

Comment: It means nothing, as the compiler errors would tell you if you tried to compile it.

Comment: This question has been asked in interview, and I didn't know what is mean. How array is creating from function?

Comment: it means: `error C2059: syntax error : ']'`

Comment: You could compile it if you provide an argumet for the subscript operator but you'll fail at [runtime](http://ideone.com/WsuZzQ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could mean that the interviewer wanted to test your reaction to being confronted with invalid source code.

I have no idea what the intention of `Func()[] = 'a';` is. The C++ compiler clang 3.4 outputs the following:

```
a.cc:3:9: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
 return "Text";
        ^
a.cc:6:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Func()[] = 'a';
^~~~
a.cc:6:5: error: function cannot return array type 'int []'
Func()[] = 'a';
```

Comment: It probably wants to know if you knew that the code is invalid and why...

Comment: it would be nice to outline why this snippet is doomed to fail since this is an answer

Answer (score 1):

Once you get it to compile (just) like this:

```
#include <iostream>

char *Func() {

 return "Text";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Func() << std::endl;

    Func()[0] = 'P';

    std::cout << Func() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You get this:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp: In function ‘char* Func()’:
main.cpp:5:9: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  return "Text";
         ^

Executing the program....
$demo 
Text
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: the original snippet doesn't use any index for the `[]` operator.

Comment: I know. Without the index it won't compile at all.